# Moving latest file within random folder structure to new location using a shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file that gets saved in a random with random names folder infrequently. Now I want to create a shellscript (`#!/bin/bash`) that finds this very latest single file and copies it to a new, fixed location (/fixed/location/latestfile.jpg) whenever I trigger the script.

What is the most forward way to achieve this? I've seen a lot of people using the command line, but I like it to be in a script.

Comment: Which shell are you targeting?

Comment: Thanks @Shawn for your question. I was thinking of `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

You can break down the problem into three parts:

1. How to get "regular" files in a directory? - Use the `find` util with `-type f`.
2. How to sort the files by modified date? - There's a stack overflow answer for this question: https://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified.
3. How to copy a file? - Easy, use `cp`

Then you can combine these parts:

1. Get the latest modified file: `find $MY_DIRECTORY -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
2. Copy it: `cp $(find $MY_DIRECTORY -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2) $DESTINATION`